# How can I find and add key / value data to hashes in Redis based on a key / value inside the hash?

Tags: database, hash, redis, key

I've got a very large number of keys in my Redis data store, all of which have very arbitrary long names of random hex text.

All of the keys that are hashes have a key inside called name, which has a value.

**How can I find a hash that has a certain unique name value when I don't know where it is by the key?** (So I have to search through all of my hashes for this - very bad I know) - for instance, add the field `color: blue` to the hash where I have unique `name: f-377`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you create addition hash that will be contains all this unique values with mapping on long name. aka own index.

So you need create new hash, go trough all existed keys and add fields (one per each key). And in future when you need to create new key - you need to add new field into index hash too.
Search in this index hash - O(1), the best what you can get.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not the one who controls the original propagation of this data.

Comment: So this is bad. Search across all keys is very expensive - O(n), there is no other way to find your requested object faster than add new index structure. You can just use Lua scripting https://redis.io/commands/eval to have more strict contract with others who propagate data, if it possible. You can use them like stored procedures in SQL databases.